# Is there a function like find_last_of in std but not in string?

Tags: c++, std

I know there is function

```
string::find_last_of
```

But I want to process a large chunk of char* data. I don't want to assign the char* to a string.

I know there is a std function

```
std::find
```

But it only can find char* on positive sequence. Is there such a way to find in reverse order?
 If not in std, is there a way in boost?

Comment: See [rbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin), [rend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend).

Comment: To be clear, are you searching for a single character or a substring?

Comment: @n.m. rbegin, rend need to be in a string.

Comment: @chris, currently, I just need searching for a char, further, I want to search for a substring.

Comment: @zhang no, they don't. `std::rbegin()` and `std::rend()` are standalone functions, not class methods. They work with any container that implements the the `rbegin()` and `rend()` methods, but they are also specialized for fixed arrays, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::find_end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_end)

> Searches for the last subsequence of elements [s_first, s_last) in the range [first, last).

For example

```
#include <algorithm>

char *data = ...;
char *data_end = data + size;
char toFind = ...;
char *pfind = &toFind;

char *found = std::find_end(data, data_end, pfind, pfind + 1);
if (found != data_end)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for one character, like `std::find()` does, you can use... `std::find()`. Take a look at [`std::reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

```
auto foo(char* str, std::size_t size, char to_find)
{
    auto rev_it = std::find(std::make_reverse_iterator(str + size),
                            std::make_reverse_iterator(str),
                            to_find);
    auto it = std::make_reverse_iterator(rev_it);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/algorithm/string/find.hpp) can solve this problem.

```
boost::algorithm::find_last
```

example:

```
char* s = "abcdabc";
cout << boost::algorithm::find_last(s, "b").begin() - s;
```

Answer (score 0):

For single-character searching, there is `std::ranges::find_last` now (unfortunately only in C++23; and there is no `std::find_last` counterpart)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/find_last

Example:

```cpp
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>

...

std::vector<char> str{ '1','2','2','3','4' };
auto find = std::ranges::find_last(str.begin(), str.end(), '2'); // [last '2', str.end())
assert(find.begin() == str.begin() + 2 && find.end() == str.end());
```