# C++ template function. error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from '_FwdIt1' to '_FwdIt1'

Tags: c++, templates, stl

There is a `std::find_first_of` but no `std::find_last_of`. I want to make such a template function by myself. I consulted this code [Is there a function like find_last_of in std but not in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075961/is-there-a-function-like-find-last-of-in-std-but-not-in-string?noredirect=1#comment93051516_53075961)

But this function was compiled failed. The error seems strange, cannot convert from `_FwdIt1` to `_FwdIt1`. They are the same type. My compiler is visual studio 2017.

```
template<class _FwdIt1, class _FwdIt2>
        inline _FwdIt1 find_last_of(const _FwdIt1 _First1, const _FwdIt1 _Last1,
            const _FwdIt2 _First2, const _FwdIt2 _Last2)
    {
        return find_first_of(reverse_iterator(_Last1), reverse_iterator(_First1), _First2, _Last2); //error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from '_FwdIt1' to '_FwdIt1'
    }


    void test()
    {
        const char* s = "0123456789";
        char* sb = "54";
        cout<<find_last_of(s, s + strlen(s), sb, sb+strlen(sb));
    }
```

Comment: Is that the *complete* and *full* error message you get? No informational notes? Nothing else *at all*? There should be some more output which should give some hints about the problem.

Comment: Also (but unrelated to your problem), note that symbols starting with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_FwdIt1` or `_FwdIt2`) are reserved in all scopes, and that you should not use such symbol names your self. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more information.

Comment: An quick and maybe dirty way to fix this is to use `auto` as a return type.

Comment: To expand on previous comment. You have probably copied the style from the implementation of `first_first_of` on your platform.  The point is that `std::find_first_of` is part of the implementation of C++. As such, it may only use symbols that are reserved to the implementation.  If it used a symbol like `FwdIt1`, that would be broken by `#define FwdIt1 42` in your code - so they use `_FwdIt1` because you aren't allowed to write `#define _FwdIt1 42`.  Contrary-wise, the implementation is fully entitled to write '#define _FwdIt1 42` (or something much more esoteric) and break your code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I renamed _FwdIt1 to MyFwdIt1. Then the error message changed somehow.
Error C2440 'return': cannot convert from '_FwdIt1' to 'MyFwdIt1'

Comment: @Lorand, yes, haha, it worked!

Comment: What compiler are you using?  All the compilers on godbolt are complaining they want a template argument for std::reverse_iterator.

Comment: @MartinBonner, oh I forgot to mention the compiler. I use visual studio 2017

Comment: That was one of the compilers I tried on Godbolt.  Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are passing `::std::reverse_iterator` as first two parameters of `::std::find_first_of` then result will be `::std::reverse_iterator` as well and to get original iterator from it you need to use `.base()` method:

```
return _FwdIt1
{
    find_first_of
    (
         reverse_iterator(_Last1)
    ,    reverse_iterator(_First1)
    ,    _First2
    ,    _Last2
    )
    .base()
};
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KuvVeY5eYN85VpMc)

Answer (score 2):

I followed @Lorand's suggestion. changed the return type to auto, it worked.

```
    template<class MyFwdIt1,
        class _FwdIt2>
        inline auto find_last_of(const MyFwdIt1 _First1, const MyFwdIt1 _Last1,
            const _FwdIt2 _First2, const _FwdIt2 _Last2)
    {
        return std::find_first_of(reverse_iterator(_Last1), reverse_iterator(_First1), _First2, _Last2);
    }

    void test()
    {
        const char* s = "0123456789";
        char* sb = "54";
        auto it = find_last_of(s, s + strlen(s), sb, sb+strlen(sb));
        cout << it - reverse_iterator(s + strlen(s)) << endl;
    }
```

Comment: It works, but according to @VTT  what you are returning from the function is a reverse iterator, so you should keep that in mind if you want to incerement/decrement it.

Comment: Yes, this was before @VTT's answer come out. Now I use VTT's solution. :)